# Golang http handler - time taken for request

Tags: go

I am trying to set a timer to count how much time is needed for my server to finish a request and I want the timer to stop after the last byte of the response is sent.

I found that the http server will only send the response after the handler function returns.

Is there any way to add a callback after the response is sent ?

Or is there a better way to count the time taken from the first byte of the request coming in till the last byte byte of the response is sent ?

Comment: How about to use a nginx as a proxy server for your go server? Then time taken could be logged into nginx access logs.

Comment: however that's exactly what I am trying to do, replacing nginx...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easier but not as accurate way to do it would be using a middleware to wrap your handler function.

```
func timer(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        startTime := time.Now()
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        duration := time.Now().Sub(startTime)
    })
}
```

Then

```
http.Handle("/route",timer(yourHandler))
```

This is more accurately the time taken to process the request and form the response and not the time between writes.

---

If you absolutely need a more accurate duration then the parts of code you're looking to change reside in the `net/http` package.

It would be around [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=70171:70186#L2270).

The highlighted line `go c.serve(ctx)` is where the the go routine for serving the request is spawned.

```
for {
    rw, e := l.Accept()
    if e != nil {
        if ne, ok := e.(net.Error); ok && ne.Temporary() {
            if tempDelay == 0 {
                tempDelay = 5 * time.Millisecond
            } else {
                tempDelay *= 2
            }
            if max := 1 * time.Second; tempDelay > max {
                tempDelay = max
            }
            srv.logf("http: Accept error: %v; retrying in %v", e, tempDelay)
            time.Sleep(tempDelay)
            continue
        }
        return e
    }
    tempDelay = 0

    c := srv.newConn(rw)
    c.setState(c.rwc, StateNew) // before Serve can return
```

> ```
>     go func(){
>           startTime := time.Now()
>           c.serve(ctx)
>           duration := time.Now().Sub(startTime)
>     }()
> ```

```
}
```

Note : The request actually gets written in the `net.Conn` somewhere inside `l.Accept()` but the highlighted point is the only place where we can have the approximate start time and end time within the same scope in the code.

Comment: so I have to modify the standard library in order to get the time used? That seems not to be very desirable.

Comment: The best option without doing that is to use a middleware. But the time won't be as accurate as it would return the duration of processing the request / response not the actual time between writes.

Comment: @wachiu I have updated the answer with the best you can do in your current code.